# Bijective Function from N to N x N

Tags: functions, natural-numbers

I have an idea but I don't know how to formalize my idea in a function. That's what n should give me back as (x,y):

```
n = 0 -> (0,0)
n = 1 -> (1,0)
n = 2 -> (0,1)
n = 3 -> (2,0)
n = 4 -> (1,1)
n = 5 -> (0,2)
n = 6 -> (3,0)
n = 7 -> (2,1)
n = 8 -> (1,2)
n = 9 -> (0,3)
n = 10 -> (4,0)
```

How do I formulate a function for this one?
I also need one for N -> N x {1,...,n) but I think it's the same function, is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each $n \in \mathbb N$ can be uniquely written as $n=m(m+1)/2 + j$ with 
$0 \le j \le m$, namely $m = \left\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2} \right\rfloor$.
Then take $f(n) = (m-j,j)$.

It's simpler, though, to write the inverse function from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$:

$$ (i,j) \mapsto \frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}+j $$

Comment: That looks very irritating for me. If I try it with n = 1, then I get m = 1 and j = 0, means f(n) = (1,0) which is true. But if I try it with n = 2, I need to take the root of 17. But that wouldn't result in a natural number for m. Where is my error?

Comment: @corenoob Note the floor operation

Comment: @Bram28. Thanks. I'm such an idiot.

How do you guys come up with such functions? I'm a c.s. student in the 2nd semester but I wouldn't be able to come up with the function above.

Comment: @CoreNoob The bijection you indicated is pretty standard, even as the actual function is a pain to figure out. My guess is Robert had this function laying around in his notes somewhere ... though it's possible he figured it out on the spot!

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. If $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, there is a unique pair $(x_n,y_n)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} $ such that $n = 2^{x_n-1}\cdot (2y_n - 1)$ (using [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)), defining the map

\begin{align*}F:&\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\\
&n\rightarrow (x_n,y_n)
\end{align*}
you get a bijection.

Comment: Thanks for this one. But that is N x N -> N and not N -> N x N, right?
f(n) would be N -> N x N.

Comment: So you can use the inverse of $F$, $F^{-1} (n,m) = 2^{n-1} \cdot (2m - 1)$

Comment: If you are concerned about the domain of $F$, is correct, this map associates every natural $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ to a pair $(x_n,y_n)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$

Comment: What is the inverse function of f(n,m) = 2^(n-1) * (2m-1) ?

Comment: The inverse of $f $ is the function $F $ that I explain in my answer. Just observe that $F (f (n,m)) =(n,m) $

Comment: Sry, I don't get it. I can't see a function in your answer where I can put in a n and get back a pair (x,y). I just see the inverse of it: Put in x,y and get n.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77493/discussion-between-corenoob-and-matheus-manzatto).

Comment: I figured out how I can put in n and get (x,y). 
You can write f(n) = f(2^v * u) = (v+1, (u+1)/2)
where v+1 = x and (u+1)/2 = y.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the formula: $0$ cannot be written as $2^a(2b-1)$. I think the mapping $2^{x_n}(2y_n+1)-1$ works though ...

Comment: If I remember this correctly, I am not considering $0 \in \mathbb N$ (which goes a bit against the def proposed by the OP...)